# How to call value compared with the previous day's value in stock exchange?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

[image]

Hi, I'd like to know how to call value compared with the previous day's value in English.

This image is what I screen-captured in tradingview.com

Q1. how do you call these value in English? -> (0.37%, 0.78%, 0.25%)

Q2. how do you call these value in English? -> (9.3, 46.2, 0.00297)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My investment manager labels this 'Change'. I imagine that if they displayed the actual price difference as well as the proportional difference they'd label them something like 'Change' and 'Change%'

[image: change]

Comment: Hi @stoneyB, long time no speak. I'm around a bit now after a bit of a mad time way. I'm missing having occasional interactions with the venerable Stony. I haven't annoyed you somehow, I hope?

Comment: @Araucaria Hi, A--Not at all; I've just been slammed for the last six months or so, and had to pull back from the sociable side of the EL sites. And in large part from the Q&A, too--but that's also ?discontent ?misgivings with my current understanding of how the language works